# Neo4j: How to exclude certain relationships where certain node as source node in MATCH

Tags: database, graph, neo4j, cypher

For example:
[image: Custom outdegree relationships not needed]

My Cypher query was:

```
MATCH p=(a:AbstractEvent)-[r:NEXT]->(c:AbstractEvent)
WHERE NOT id(a) in [115]
RETURN p
```

But the result still includes the 115 "Customer" node's outgoing relationship to "UI.Click" node. To make it clear, I still need the 115 "Customer" node, but without those outgoing relationships.

How to exclude all the outgoing relationship of a node when MATCH?

And btw, what's the difference between `RETURN p` and `RETURN a,r,c` in this example?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Neo4j Browser setting, the 'Connect result nodes' option is enabled by default. All relationships between the nodes matched in your query will be displayed with this enabled, even if you haven't explicitly mentioned that path/pattern/relationship in your query.

You can find this option in the Browser Settings, available in the bottom left corner of your Neo4j Browser.

[Adjust the Graph Visualization settings in the Browser Settings drawer](https://neo4j.com/docs/browser-manual/current/operations/browser-settings/#adjust-in-browser)

With this option enabled, `RETURN p`, `RETURN a,r,c` and `RETURN a,c` will all show the same graph output.
But if you disable the 'Connect result nodes' option, the result graph will only include relationships that you specify in the Return statement.`RETURN p`, `RETURN a,r,c` will fetch the entire path but `RETURN a,c` will only fetch the nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Neo4j UI option called 'Graph' will present you **all** the relationships between the selected nodes, regardless of the relationships returned from your query. So if node 115 is returned (as c), you will see all its relationships with other returned nodes. If you want to check your "real" query result, use 'Table', 'Text' or 'Code', options on the top left. Not 'Graph'.